How to properly quote this piped command for "watch"?
I want to use the watch command to continuously monitor the following piped command, but watch always fails no matter how I quote it:
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player string:Metadata | sed -n '/title/{n;p}' | cut -d '"' -f 2


Switch to double quotes in your command to make your life easier:
watch 'dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player string:Metadata | sed -n "/title/{n;p}" | cut -d \" -f 2'

